# Paytm Integration in my application

Tags: java, android, transactions, paytm

I create sandbox account in paytm.I am using github code and pass merchant id and all parameter to paytm.please check my below code

```
public void onStartTransaction(View view) {
    PaytmPGService Service = PaytmPGService.getStagingService();
    Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // these are mandatory parameters

    paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.order_id)).getText().toString());
    paramMap.put("MID", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.merchant_id)).getText().toString());
    paramMap.put("CUST_ID", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.customer_id)).getText().toString());
    paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.channel_id)).getText().toString());
    paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.industry_type_id)).getText().toString());
    paramMap.put("WEBSITE", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.website)).getText().toString());
    paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.transaction_amount)).getText().toString());
    paramMap.put("THEME", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.theme)).getText().toString());
    paramMap.put("EMAIL", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.cust_email_id)).getText().toString());
    paramMap.put("MOBILE_NO", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.cust_mobile_no)).getText().toString());
    PaytmOrder Order = new PaytmOrder(paramMap);

    PaytmMerchant Merchant = new PaytmMerchant(
            "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumGenerator.jsp",
            "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumVerify.jsp");


    Service.initialize(Order, Merchant, null);

    Service.startPaymentTransaction(this, true, true,
            new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void someUIErrorOccurred(String inErrorMessage) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ui/Webview error occured.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onTransactionSuccess(Bundle inResponse) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "Payment Transaction is successful " + inResponse);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Payment Transaction is successful ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTransactionFailure(String inErrorMessage,
                        Bundle inResponse) {
                    Log.d("LOG", "Payment Transaction Failed " + inErrorMessage);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Payment Transaction Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    recreate();
                }

                @Override
                public void networkNotAvailable() {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String inErrorMessage) {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Client Authentication Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int iniErrorCode,
                        String inErrorMessage, String inFailingUrl) {

                }


                @Override
                public void onBackPressedCancelTransaction() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

            });
}
```

below attachment I pass parameter to PaytmPGService.please check attachment

[image]

after click on confirm order I got this screen please check attachment

[image]

so please check and help me...

Comment: It seems that you are using PayTM SDK. I've worked with PayTM API integration and this error came in case of invalid checksum hash

Answer (score 0):

there is also some server side implementation, make sure your chechksum is generated from server.

Answer (score 0):

Several things to take care:

Confirm you supply all required arguments for checksum generation to your server.

Make sure when paytm hits your server url, it generates same checksum as it was returned back to your app.

Your credentials are configured in their staging server while testing on staging, and same on their production server.

Make sure from their side if they have enabled all required options like cc/dc etc.